# CSV has no carriage return but sqlloader has inserted space during load

Tags: sql, excel, csv, sql-loader

I have an **excel(csv)** file with two columns `(col1, col2)..` with no extra spaces in both columns.

But during data load using `SQL LOADER, Col2` gets inserted with extra space at the end.

I tried to open the `csv file` *(in notepad++, excel)* and couldnt see any extra spaces.. suspected it to be carriage return. But there is no such carriage return explicitly in `csv` to view...

I atlast replaced it after loading as below:

`UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL2 = REPLACE(COL2,CHR(13),'') WHERE 1=1;`

My question is : How to remove such carriage returns in excel or `csv` (which is not visible) before data load...

Comment: You need to show an excerpt from your data file, and your control file at the least.

Comment: Below is the control file ...   OPTIONS(skip=1)
load data
infile  '$HOME/SQLLoader/Files/file_1.csv' 
INTO TABLE table1 TRUNCATE FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' optionally enclosed by '"'TRAILING NULLCOLS
(col1,col2)

Comment: any updates wil be helpful...